# Retrieve cell information from excel file in Sharepoint Online using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint-online

In Excel I can read data from another cell in a closed spreadsheet that is on Sharepoint Online by using this formula.

='https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/Site/Shared Documents/[Excel.xlsx]Sheet'!A1

It doesn't visibly open any workbooks files to get this information.

How do I get the data using VBA, say to set a string value. Every guidance I have seen involves Workbooks.open but I think it shouldn't be necessary to open the workbook?

Comment: Your formula won't update unless the source workbook is open, so it doesn't give you a way to get around opening the workbook to update the value.

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams. They do when they are just in the spreadsheet. I don't need to open anything. It just gets the data from the Sharepoint server. I feel I should be able to do the same query with VBA.